# PHP - Variable inside <form action=" "> attribute as part of url for get method

Tags: php, get

Trying to pass a php variable inside the action attribute for html forms as part of the get method of passing variables through url based on the option that was selected.

```
 <?php 
 ...
 $sql = "SELECT staffID, staffName
 FROM staff";

$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error($conn));
?>
    <form action = "task7.php?" method = "get"> 
        <select>
        <?php 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        {
            $staffID = $row["staffID"]; 
            $staffName = $row["staffName"];
        ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo $staffID ?>"> <?php echo $staffName ?> </option>
        <?php 
        } 
        ?> 
        </select>

        <br> <br> 
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"> 
        <input type = "reset" value = "Reset">  

    </form>
```

In this particular case I'm trying to pass the staffID variable as part of the url. Something like this `tast7.php?staffID=12345`

Comment: Why not pass it as a hidden input variable in the form? Or alternatively pass it as a Mod_rewrite address (submitting form to `/tast7/staff12345/`)

Comment: and what is the problem? `<form action="task7.php?<?php echo $variable; ?>" method="get">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All thats missing from your code is a name on the `select`

```
 <select name="staffID">  <!-- adding the name will append the selected value to the url -->
    <?php 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $staffID = $row["staffID"]; 
        $staffName = $row["staffName"];
    ?>
    <option value = "<?php echo $staffID ?>"> <?php echo $staffName ?> </option>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?> 
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks almost worked except the problem now is I'm getting this in the url

tast7.php?%24staffID=12345

the %24 needs to go.

Comment: %24 is a url encoded "$" I can't see where its coming from in your code though

Comment: I added a $ like this <select name="$staffID">. I've removed the $ sign and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Accepting an answer is the stack over thank you mechanism :)

Answer (score 1):

In php,

```
<form action = "task7.php" method = "get"> 
    <select name="staffID">
    <?php 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
    ?>

    <option value = "<?php echo $row["staffID"]; ?>"> <?php echo $row["staffName"]; ?> </option>

    <?php 
    } 
    ?> 
    </select>
    <br> <br> 
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"> 
    <input type = "reset" value = "Reset">  
</form>
```

You may do it using jQuery/JS easily.

Eg : (Using jQuery)

```js
function formSubmit(element){
  var url = $("#test").attr("action", "");
  url += "?" + element.name + "=" + element.value;
  $("#test").attr("action", url);
  $("#test")[0].submit();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test.php" method="get" id="test">
  <select name="id" onChange="formSubmit(this)">
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="xyz">xyz</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$id = 1;


//later

<form action = "task7.php?staffID="+<?= $id ?> method = "get">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking too complicated. Have a try like that:

```
<form action = "task7.php" method = "get"> 
    <select name="staffID">
    <?php 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $staffID = $row["staffID"]; 
        $staffName = $row["staffName"];
    ?>
    <option value = "<?php echo $staffID ?>"> <?php echo $staffName ?> </option>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?> 
    </select>
    <br> <br> 
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"> 
    <input type = "reset" value = "Reset">  
</form>
```

What you are looking for is *not* a "php variable". Such thing does not exist on the client side. Instead you simply want to submit the value chosen for your `<select>` tag as a simple "HTTP GET" parameter. That is exactly what a form tag with method `GET` does. You just have to name your option select, that's all: `<select name="staffID">`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its almost working except the url is now: tast7.php?%24staffID=12345

Trying to get rid of the %24

Comment: Most likely that is because instead of using above code you modifed it and use `<select name="$staffID">` instead of the correct `<select name="staffID">`... As said before: on the client side, there is no `php`. So you only want to use a literal name for the select option. That has _nothing_ to do with a "php variable" at that time.

Comment: That is correct. I've fixed it now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great! You really want to invest some time into really understanding how those components work together.